# Thunderbird: how do I recover lost emails after sync

Tags: windows-7, email, sync, thunderbird, system-recovery

There was update on email servers and some of my emails were deleted. I logged through Thunderbird (where I store my emails locally) and it started to sync with the servers. I closed it asap, but now I lost some of my old folders. Of course, I would not ask this question here if I had a recent backup...
I'd like to ask: is there a way to restore them?... Could perhaps system recovery (Windows 7) also restore the thunderbird profile?